# Modify relationship association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a micro-social-network and I have two different account types, User can either be Profile or Page.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  has_one :page

end
```

Now, when I want to show the User name, I do current_user.profile.name, but if the User is a "Page", I get an error, obviously.

So I tried this

```
private
  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])

      if @current_user.account_type == 'profile'
        @current_user.profile = @current_user.page
      end

    end
  end
```

But it's not working.

Any help is appreciated greatly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a bit confusing -- if the account type is a profile, why would you set its profile as a page? Also, I am not sure what `@current_user.profile = @current_user.page` would be doing, but `@current_user.profile` stores the foreign key to `profile`, so you would need to store the `id` of `page` if you really wanted to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the "profile" var of the current_user, and he has none, and set the profile to the page. so I don't have to be changed between current_user.profile and current_user.page in every single view. Instead, I just use current_user.profile for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are asking, but you can add a method to `User` model to handle this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  has_one :page

  def name
     if self.account_type == 'profile'
        return self.profile.name

     return <whatever for page>
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

For multiple fields, why not use a method for `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # other code removed

  def get_info(method, *args)
      if self.account_type == 'profile'
          return self.profile.send(method, *args)
      end
      self.page.send(method, *args)
  end 
end
```

So to use this, say we have `a = User.find(:id)` with any `id`. Then, you can do, assuming `a`'s `account_type` is `profile`:

`a.get_info(:name) # => a.profile.name`

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I have a LOT of fields, for example, Profile has name, age, gender and many more. Then, Page has name, description, address, country and so on

Comment: I added more if you wanted to do that.

Comment: Yeah, but now I did current_user.name and got nothing, or am I using it wrong? It's the first time I've seen method_missing

Comment: I removed the method_missing since it would be better to make a custom method to handle this.

Comment: Amazing. I really appreciate your help TheDude!